# Inner and Outer Product of 2 rank tensors

Tags: tensor-products, matrix-calculus

I am trying to figure out whether or not the following identity is true:

$D_{kl}A_{ij}A_{kl}=A_{kl}D_{kl}A_{ij}$

Or what I think is qually:

$D:(A\otimes A)= (A:D)A$

The matrices are both symmetric $A=A^T, B=B^T$.

I tried to "prove" it by simply doing the calculus with 2x2 matrices but I always end up wit another (wrong) result. I would very much appreciate it if you could help me or give me some hints whether this is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When employing index notation, you are effectively just summing over repeated indices, so if the resulting matrix is $M$, then

$$ M_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n D_{kl}A_{ij}A_{kl}= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^nA_{kl}D_{kl}A_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n A_{ij}D_{kl}A_{kl}= \cdots
$$

The terms being multiplied inside the summation can be taken in any order.

Thus, given definitions for "$\otimes$" and "$:$" you can come up with different interpretations to an operation which is effectively just summing up the product of elements in two matrices/tensors in a certain order. All this provided the dimensions of the matrices allow for such an operation.